# HTTPTask response into Swifty for JSON serialization

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I'm using HTTPTask to load data from openweathermap.org. Which is working fine. I'm having trouble converting the data to JSON. I'd like to use SwiftyJSON but, I can't quite figure out how to bridge the two.

HTTPTask has a JSON Serializer, which I got working, but I rather use Swifty, it's seems easier to work with.

Here's what I have so far. This loads the weather from openweathermap.org. I'm not sure how to pass the response into Swifty.

```
var request = HTTPTask()
request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()
request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()

request.GET(openWeatherURL, parameters: ["q":"San Francisco", "APPID":openWeatherAPIKey], success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
    if let dict = response.responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        println("Response: \(response)")
        println("Dictionary: \(dict)")
        let description = dict["weather"]["description"]
        println(description)
                }
}, failure: {(error: NSError, repsonse: HTTPResponse?) in
    println("error \(error)")
})
```

Comment: I haven't used HTTPTask, but it seems likely that you could write your own request serializer that implements .GET etc. with SwiftyJSON doing the legwork.

That said, two thoughts for you: 1) ask yourself why you even want to do this; you've already got a native swift Dictionary with very little effort. 2) If you don't like working with Dictionary, SwiftyJSON will happily wrap it as is: `JSON(dict)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I didn't realize I could pass a dictionary to Swifty JSON().

Comment: Oh, well in that case I'll go ahead and submit it as a proper answer so you can mark it, and in case it might help somebody else. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftyJSON is quite happy to take a variety of objects, including Dictionary?, so just go for it!

```
let dict = JSON(response.responseObject)
```