# Fill in Dictionary with Swifty JSON response?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I've got (swiftyJSON) string coming back that looks like :

```
{
"siteName1" : "http://www.example1.com/",
"siteName2" : "http://www.example2.com/",
"siteName3" : "http://www.example3.com"
}
```

How would you fill the dictionary below :

```
let dictAvailableTracks = [String:String]()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPTask response into Swifty for JSON serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762299/httptask-response-into-swifty-for-json-serialization). See clozach's answer.

Answer (score 1):

after you get your data from your webservice, serialize it to JSON first:

```
let serializedResponse: JSON = JSON(response)
```

afterwards you can get the dictionary like this:

```
let dictAvailableTracks = serializedResponse.dictionaryObject
```

`dictAvailableTracks` is then a dictionary of type `[String:AnyObject]` but you can cast it to `[String:String]`.

```
let dictAvailableTracks = serializedResponse.dictionaryObject as [String:String]
```

Comment: please add explnation along with the code snippet for better understanding

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm.  since I'm new to swift .. it seems the real issue I was having problems with was I declared my dictionary variable as a global and not within the function itself.